# CSS Floats not breaking properly

Tags: css, html

I have a CSS file, mastercss4.css:

```
#content {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#top {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 141px;
    background-color: red;
}

#topleft {
    width: 193px;
    height: 141px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;       
}

#topmid {
    width: 15px;
    height: 141px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

#topright {
    width: 797px;
    height: 141px;
    background-color: cyan;
    float: left;
}

#middle {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 598px;
    background-color: white;
    float: clear;
}

#midleft {
    width: 188px;
    height: 598px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    float: left;    
}

#midmid {
    width: 15px;
    height: 598px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}

#midright {
    width: 797px;
    height: 598px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    float: left;
}

#bottom {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 61px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: clear;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

I have an HTML file, default09.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="test">
        <meta name="author" content="Algomeysa">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mastercss4.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="top">
                <div id="topleft">tl</div> 
                <div id="topmid"></div> 
                <div id="topright">tr</div> 
            </div> 
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="midleft">ml</div> 
                <div id="midmid"></div> 
                <div id="midright">mr</div> 
            </div> 
            <div id="bottom">bottom</div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

what should result is the Red, White, and Blue bars completely overwritten
Top row: Yellow box, thin Green section, Cyan box
Middle row: Aquamarine box, thin Orange section, Blueviolet box
Bottom row: Blue box

What happens instead is the top right cyan box gets dropped down to the middle left, and everything else is staggered.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes please mark one as the correct answer. If you found the answer on your own please add the solution as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

set topright width to 792px. You have 5 more pixels than your parent container width:

```
#topright{
  width: 792px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clear` is not a valid value for the `float` property. `left`, `right`, `none`, `initial` and `inherit` are the only valid values for `float`.

`clear` itself is a css property and accepts `left`, `right`, `both`, `none`, `initial` or `inherit`.

It looks like you have a couple of instances of `float: clear;` in your code. Change those to something like `clear: both;` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

make it simple just change

> float:none

to ***#topright***

and reduce the width of topright as rquired